# Странное поведение кнопок добавления и удаления в дереве

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Написал код добавления и удаления выделенных веток в дереве. Но наблюдается странное и неправильное поведение. Например, если добавляю один дочерний элемент 1 выделяю его и нажимаю на кнопку в него добавляется дочерний, если выделяю 2 в него тоже добавляется дочерний, а нужно добавлять только в тот элемент, который расположен рядом с кнопкой, а не в другие. Может быть можно как-то через свойство Tag делать проверку, но свойство Tag постоянно изменяется. Как исправить проблему с кнопками?

```
TreeViewItem sel = new TreeViewItem();

public void treeviewS_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs <object> e) {
    sel = treeviewS.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
}

if (sel.IsSelected == true) {
    int sum = 1;

    for (x = 0; x <= sel.Items.Count;) {
        sum *= x;

        x++;

        newChild2 = new TreeViewItem();
        newChild2.Header = "Подраздел " + sel.Tag.ToString().Replace("s", string.Empty) + "-" + x.ToString();
        newChild2.Tag = "s".TrimStart().ToString() + sel.Tag.ToString() + "-" + x.ToString();

        TreeViewItem childparentSystemCatalog2 = new TreeViewItem();

        sp = new StackPanel();

        sp.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;

        tb2 = new TextBlock();

        tb2.Text = "Подразделы " + newChild2.Tag.ToString();
        tb2.Tag = newChild2.Tag.ToString();

        bb5 = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
        bb5.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
        bb5.ToolTip = "Добавить подраздел";
        bb5.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGreen;
        bb5.Content = "доб.";

        bb5.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(bb5_Click);

        System.Windows.Controls.Button b5 = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
        b5.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
        b5.ToolTip = "Удалить подраздел";
        b5.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGreen;
        b5.Content = "удал.";

        b5.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(b5_Click);

        sp.Children.Add(tb2);
        sp.Children.Add(bb5);
        sp.Children.Add(b5);

        childparentSystemCatalog2.Header = sp;

        childparentSystemCatalog2.Tag = " " + newChild2.Tag.ToString();

        newChild2.Items.Add(childparentSystemCatalog2);
    }

    sel.Items.Add(newChild2);
}
```